# "Увидеть по телевидению" или "увидеть по телевизору"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Он пришел в удивление, увидев ее **по телевидению**

или

Он пришел в удивление, увидев ее **по телевизору**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта верны, второй тяготеет к разговорной речи. Но нарочито говорить "по телевидению" не стоит, если вы не выступаете с докладом и не пишете реферат.

"Пришел в удивление" тоже вряд ли стоит говорить. Прийти можно в негодование, в изумление и т.д. А у вас просто "он удивился" или "очень удивился".

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо как "пришел в удивление", так и "удивился", как "по телевидению", так и "по телевизору". Дело в нюансах. "Пришел в удивление" - высокий стиль, "удивился" - нейтральный, "по телевидению" чуть-чуть тяготеет к высокому, "по телевизору" - чуть-чуть тяготеет к разговорному.